# Selecionar valor do select e abrir diferentes links ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde, estou precisando de uma ajuda, preciso selecionar o valor da escolha de um select e chamar um link diferente para valor, ao clicar no botão.

```
<div>
   <button onclick="redirecionar()">COMPRAR</button>

   <select id="cor">
      <option value="1">BRANCO</option>
      <option value="2">PRETO</option>
      <option value="3">VERDE</option>
   </select>

   <script>
      var valor = document.getElementById('cor');
      function redirecionar() {

         window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.br";
      }
      if (valor == "2") {
         window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com.br";
      }
      if (valor == "3") {
         window.location.href = "http://www.youtube.com.br";
      }

   }
   </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem alguns problemas, vc tem que declarar o **if** dentro da função, tem que pegar a propriedade **value** dos `options`, também tem uma chave a mais sobrando no código, além de não ser muito recomendado declarar um script em uma tag **`div`**:

```js
var valor = document.getElementById('cor');

function redirecionar() {
  if(valor.value == "1") window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com.br";
  else if(valor.value == "2") window.location.href = "http://www.youtube.com.br";
  else window.location.href = "http://www.google.com.br";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="redirecionar()">COMPRAR</button>

  <select id="cor">
    <option value="1">BRANCO</option>
    <option value="2">PRETO</option>
    <option value="3">VERDE</option>
  </select>
  
</div>
```